# How do I hide the file extension in Finder?

Tags: macos, finder

On my mac, when I go to the folder Applications  see the format ".app"
How can I hide it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right click on finder left panel choose "open sidebar preferences" go to advance tab uncheck the "show all file extension"

[image]

Comment: I uncheck the first checkbox but its still show the .api

Comment: @Daniel, can you post a screenshot of what you have.  @Am1rr3zA's answer is correct.  But in your question you state .app and in your comment .api    I think you are trying to hide file extensions, which is what was answered above.